# I am taking import error after transforming py file to exe but when i change the code.py file's name, the error disappears

Tags: python, importerror

```css
# That's run.py
from code import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

```html
# That's code.py that i created

import mouse
import keyboard
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
    def init_ui(self):
        self.processbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Collect")
        self.processbutton.clicked.connect(self.click)
        
        self.upgradebutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Upgrade Launcher")
        self.upgradebutton.clicked.connect(self.click)
        
        
        

        self.warninglabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        
        # datetime
        now = datetime.now()
        date = datetime.strftime(now,"%Y %B %d %A")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(date)
        cday = 28
        cdate = datetime.strftime(now,"%d")
        cdate = int(cdate)
        if cdate >= cday:
            self.warninglabel.setText("DO NOT FORGET TO COLLECT GIFTS!!")

        
        
        
        
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.processbutton)
        hlayout.addStretch()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.upgradebutton)
        
        datetimelayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        datetimelayout.addStretch()
        datetimelayout.addWidget(self.label)
        datetimelayout.addStretch()

        warninglayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        warninglayout.addStretch()
        warninglayout.addWidget(self.warninglabel)


        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.addStretch()
        vlayout.addLayout(datetimelayout)
        vlayout.addLayout(warninglayout)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        
        self.setLayout(vlayout)
        
        self.show()
    def click(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender.text() == "Collect":
            os.startfile("C:\Program Files\RotMG Exalt Launcher\Rotmg Exalt Launcher.exe")
            mouse.move(1250,600)
            time.sleep(10)
            mouse.click('left')
            time.sleep(1)
            mouse.move(1250,800)
            mouse.click('left')
            time.sleep(1)
            mouse.click('left')
            time.sleep(40)
            # close app
            mouse.click('left')
            keyboard.press("alt")
            keyboard.press("f4")
            keyboard.release("f4")
            keyboard.release("alt")
            os.close("C:\Program Files\RotMG Exalt Launcher\Rotmg Exalt Launcher.exe")
        elif sender.text() == "Upgrade Launcher":
            webbrowser.open("https://www.realmofthemadgod.com/build/download?platform=standalonewindows64")
            
def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I made a file named code.py that has pyqt5 module codes and made another file named run.py and imported code.py but windows raised import error named "run.py" from "code.py" but when i change the name of code.py the error disappeared but code.py is corrupted even if i change the python commands in the code.py it won't work.
Before that error,i created a shortcut of run.py, i accidentally changed the target from the properties.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clearly include your actual code.  How are you 'importing' code.py in run.py?   What errors did you get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i thought there's another file that named code.py :/ i searched code.py in all files and found another code.py that i dont know what is about.

Answer (score 0):

I just Checked all code.py files and found code.py files in my AppData/Roaming directory. I thought these are corrupted and deleted them. As a result of that, import error is fixed. Thank you for your comments :)